# variable not declared error in OriginPro data fitting

Tags: c++

I'm trying to build a function in the program OriginPro, but I am getting a variable not declared error when compiling the script. The script is supposed to solve a cubic equation with the coefficients a, b, c, and d, using Newman's iterative method, then use the solution to optimise the the parameters K1, K2, E0, E1, E2, and Gt (Not part of the script, OriginPro does this) before reusing the optimised parameters to solve the cubic equation again. I am getting the error "variable "a" not declared" when compiling the script. I pasted the script below here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
//----------------------------------------------------------
// 
void _nlsfNMR2to1Iterative(
// Fit Parameter(s):
double K1, double K2, double E0, double E1, double E2, double Gt,
// Independent Variable(s):
double x,
// Dependent Variable(s):
double& y)
{
// Beginning of editable part
a=K1*K2;
b=K1+2*K2*K1*x-K1*K2*Gt;
c=1+K1*x-K1*Gt;
d=-Gt;

for(G=x, step=1; abs(step)>1e-15; G=G-step){
    step=(a*G*G*G+b*G*G+c*G+d)/(3*a*G*G+2*b*G+c);};

y=E0*G+Ht*(E1*K1*G+E2*K1*K2*G*G)/(1+K1*G+K1*K2*G*G)
// End of editable part
}
```

Comment: error is clear what is `a`? it is not defined, this cannot be your complete code

Comment: I cannot see either of `a`, `b`, `c` or `d` anywhere here....

Comment: How do I declare the variables?

Comment: C++ is not C is not C++!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a type to the declarations of `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d`.

Change:

```
a=K1*K2;
b=K1+2*K2*K1*x-K1*K2*Gt;
c=1+K1*x-K1*Gt;
d=-Gt;
```

to

```
double a=K1*K2;
double b=K1+2*K2*K1*x-K1*K2*Gt;
double c=1+K1*x-K1*Gt;
double d=-Gt;
```

Comment: That seemed to do it for a, b, c, and d. Now it gives me the same error with G - should I add that to my list of dependant variables?